# plotting a graph using the foldr function

Tags: scheme, racket, fold

So for my HW problem, I have do to this: A few examples:
(plot (build-list 9 (lambda (x) (make-point (* 0.1 (add1 x)) (* 0.1 (add1 x)))))) 
[image]

(plot (build-list 9 (lambda (x) (make-point (* 0.1 (add1 x)) (- 1 (* 0.1 (add1 x)))))))

Use foldr in your implementation.
[image]

However, I do not know how to do this using foldr. Is there a method I should be doing this? Is there some invisible line that traverses through the equation of the line and the points are put a slopes' distance from another? Are all the points on top of a square that is x pixels wide and long? I honestly do not even know how to tackle this problem since I do not really understand how I would implement this. Some pointers on how to do this problem would be fantastic!

Comment: At the very least, please copy the text and properly format your question rather than have everyone open this huge picture in a new tab. Thanks.

Comment: How about you add the code that you have so far. Lets start with a function that plots a rectangle with a single point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say we have the points (1,2) (3,4) and (5,6).
Without plot we could plot these points like this:

```
(plot-point (make-point 1 2)
            (plot-point (make-point 3 4)
                        (plot-point (make-point 5 6)
                                    blank-image)))
```

where plot-point takes two arguments, a point and an image to draw the point on top of.

What should plot do?

Let's call the points p1, p2 and p3. Plot should transform

```
   (cons p1 (cons p2 (cons p3 empty)))
```

to

```
   (plot-point p1 (plot-point p2 (plot-point p3 blank-image)))).
```

How can foldr help with that?

Comment: I don't know how to make the argument for plot-point. I cant get to get this code to work.

Comment: That is the correct way of using foldr.

Comment: I know how foldr works, I just dont know how to set plot-point to do what I want it to do. If I want the blank-image to be a square that can change size depending on the function, I do not really know how that would work and how I can implement it into the foldr function without there being an error.

Comment: Take a look at overlay/xy here: http://docs.racket-lang.org/teachpack/2htdpimage.html?q=htdp#%28def._%28%28lib._2htdp%2Fimage..rkt%29._overlay%2Fxy%29%29

Comment: So I created this function using the overlay/xy: (define (plot-point lst blank-image)
  (overlay/xy (circle 1 'solid 'red)
              (point-x (first lst) point-x (plot-point (rest lst) blank-image))
              (point-y (first lst) point-y (plot-point (rest lst) blank-image))
              (blank-image)))                                           But there is something wrong with it and I do not know what it is. do I want plot-point to be recursive or not? Will foldr do the recursion for me and as long as I have one point, foldr will take care of the rest?

Comment: The function plot-point only plots one point, not a list of points.

Comment: I forgot to say this but I eventually decided to use overlay/align/offset instead and it ended up working out. Thanks for the help though! Your pointer was really helpful.

Comment: Forgot to do that, sorry